# Popular Listview UWP C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, uwp

Estou usando um banco em `sqlite`, já feito e com dados na minha aplicação `UWP` e tentando exibir em um `listview` os dados que estão na tabela `Marcas`.

O que fiz até agora foi criar uma classe `Marcas`:

```
public class Marcas
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

}
```

Criei um `listview` na tela

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="800" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500">
        <ListView.Header>
            <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Imagem}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descricao}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

A propriedade:

```
public ObservableCollection<Marcas> obs_Marcas { get; set; }
```

e o método pra pegar os registros do banco:

```
 List<Marcas> oMarcas = conn.Query<Marcas>("Select * From Marcas");

 obs_Marcas = new ObservableCollection<Marcas>();
 foreach (Marcas marca in oMarcas)
 {
     obs_Marcas.Add(new Marcas { Nome = marca.Nome, 
                                 Descricao = marca.Descricao, 
                                 Imagem = marca.Imagem 
                                }
                    );
 }
 listView.ItemsSource = obs_Marcas;
```

Debugando, o objeto `obs_Marcas` está preenchido corretamente, com os dados do banco. Na hora do `obs_Marcas.Add`, nome, descricao e imagem estão sendo preenchidos corretamente, mas na aplicação a lista fica com todos os registros como `GeraBanner.Marcas`.

O que eu fiz errado e como exibir os dados corretamente?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6099324-e66c-42ef-9bfe-a0f022e2b6ab/twoway-binding-working-on-strings-but-not-on-datetimes-and-int-release-preview?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `layout` usado que está com **problemas**, postei um que pode ser um `layout` recomendável para seu problema e vai trazer as informações em cada ***bloco separado***:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="800" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Imagem}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descricao}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>           
</ListView>
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Binding Collection To ListView Control In UWP](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5ef5aa/binding-collection-to-listview-control-in-uwp-explained/)
- [Contêineres e modelos de itens](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/listview-item-templates)

Comment: opa, era isso mesmo, pode me explicar o que estava errado?

Comment: @Marceloawq é você colocou um `ListView.Header` e o correto é `ListView.ItemTemplate` esse destinado a mostrar informações de um estrutura ...